# Styling table rows as headings

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a mobile site targeting older phones that have limited CSS \ html support and so I'm reverting to tables.

What I'm trying to achieve on a particular page is to have a table row with a heading of a particular value and then another row in the same table with the value and a link to edit

The problem is that the heading spans only one column and I would like to be able to style it so that there is some padding and margins as well as a border.

Can someone provide some advice on how to do this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="navalt">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="edHeading">
            <td><fmt:message key="editprofile.location"/></fmt:message></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftTd">USA</td>
            <td class="rightTd"><a href="">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.navalt {
    text-align:center;
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 4px;
    border-top: thin solid #C5C9D1;
    border- bottom: thin solid #C5C9D1;
}
.edHeading {
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 4px;
    background-color:#E9E1FF;
}
.leftTd {
    border-right: thin solid #C5C9D1;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-align:left;
    width:50%;
}
.rightTd {
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    text-align:right;
    width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wabs said, you could just add a colspan to your `td` in the heading.

Another way, which will allow you to separate your styling more, is to use the `thead` tag - seeing as you have used `<tbody>` this would make more sense.

Also - as a side note, you have no closing tags for your `div` and `body` and `table` - though i assume this is because you only copied part of your code..?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6NKt/2/

the code is as:

**HTML**

```
<table style="width:100%;">
 <thead>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Heading - location use th tags</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="leftTd">USA</td>
    <td class="rightTd"><a href="">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
```

and **CSS** - notice use of `thead` instead

```
.navalt {text-align:center;padding: 4px 0px 4px 4px;border-top: thin solid #C5C9D1;border- bottom: thin solid #C5C9D1;}

thead {padding: 4px 0px 4px 4px;background-color:#E9E1FF;}
thead th {font-size:20px;}

.leftTd {border-right: thin solid #C5C9D1;padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;text-align:left;width:50%;}

.rightTd {padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;text-align:right;width:50%;}
```

Comment: And yes, just forgot to copy them

Comment: Out of interest, I just discovered that you can drop the thead css completely and just style th

Comment: yes you can, you can also drop the tbody. though in the interest of separating each piece of the table into it's own responsibility, its always nice to put them in. It will also allow you to target tags like `td` differently, such as `tbody td {myBodycellStyle}` and `thead td {myheadcellsyle}` - this way you won't need to define your own custom class to target the different `TD`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, could you not add `colspan=2` to the header `<td>` so it spans your entire table?

```
<tr class="edHeading"><td colspan="2"><fmt:message key="editprofile.location"/></td></tr>
```

Comment: Tried that and it solves the issue of spanning but I still can't figure out how best to implement the style for that heading